# Django - passing a dict to form constructor and having it available globally in the class

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm making a big mess trying to access the object that I passed from the view to the form.

```
class PrenotaForm(forms.ModelForm):

    ORARI_CHOICES = ()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        DICT_ORARI_CHOICES = kwargs.pop('ORARI_CHOICES_NEW', {})

        ORARI_CHOICES_NEW = []
        for key, value in DICT_ORARI_CHOICES.items():
            temp = [key,value]
            ORARI_CHOICES_NEW.append(temp)

            super(PrenotaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.ORARI_CHOICES = ORARI_CHOICES_NEW

        print("EEEEEEEEEEEEEEE" + str(self.ORARI_CHOICES))

    print(ORARI_CHOICES)
```

I don't understand why inside the init the ORARI_CHOICES is populated as shown in console output:

> EEEEEEEEEEEEEEE[['è uguale', 'Indifferente'], ['845', '08:45'], ['900', '09:00'], ['915', {'label': '09:15', 'disabled': 'disabled'}], ['930', {'label': '09:30', 'disabled': 'disabled'}], ['945', '09:45'], ['1000', '10:00'], ['1015', '10:15'], ['1030', '10:30'], ['1045', '10:45'], ['1100', '11:00'], ['1115', '11:15'], ['1130', '11:30'], ['1145', '11:45']]

but outside the init the ORARI_CHOICE is still empty:

```
print(ORARI_CHOICES)
```

since the print does not output nothing.

How can I override the `ORARI_CHOICES = ()` and make it avalable globally in the class after every GET request performed in the view?

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    size_gruppi = 30
    print("gruppi size is : " + str(size_gruppi))

    ORARI_CHOICES = (
        ('è uguale', "Indifferente"),
        ('845', "08:45"),
        ('900', "09:00"),
        ('915', "09:15"),
        ('930', "09:30"),
        ('945', "09:45"),
        ('1000', "10:00"),
        ('1015', "10:15"),
        ('1030', "10:30"),
        ('1045', "10:45"),
        ('1100', "11:00"),
        ('1115', "11:15"),
        ('1130', "11:30"),
        ('1145', "11:45"),
    )

    orari_map = map(list,ORARI_CHOICES)
    orari_dict = dict(ORARI_CHOICES)
    print(orari_dict)

    counter = 0
    for key in orari_map:
        if key[0] != 'è uguale':
            tot_in_fascia = sum(filter(None, Iscritto.objects.filter(fasce_orarie=key[0]).aggregate(Sum('size_adulti'), Sum('size_giovani')).values()))
            print(tot_in_fascia)
            if tot_in_fascia >= size_gruppi:
                print("fascia " + key[0] + " è al completo ")
                orari_dict.update({key[0]: {'label': key[1], 'disabled': 'disabled'}})

    form = PrenotaForm(ORARI_CHOICES_NEW = orari_dict)
    return render(request, "prenota.html", {'form': form, 'posti_liberi': posti_disponibili, 'giovani_iscritti': giovani_iscritti})
```

Comment: Firstly, you defined a new local variable which hid the class-level one. Secondly, as with any Python class attribute, you would need to refer to it via `self`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have tried to modify the code as you suggested (see edited question) , but apparently I cannot use "self" outside the __init__ method: ´print(self.DICT_ORARI_CHOICES)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined´

Answer (score 1):

You should set `ORARI_CHOICES` as a class/static attribute.

```
class PrenotaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ORARI_CHOICES = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        DICT_ORARI_CHOICES = kwargs.pop('ORARI_CHOICES_NEW', {})

        # ORARI_CHOICES_NEW = []
        for key, value in DICT_ORARI_CHOICES.items():
            temp = [key,value]
            self.__class__.ORARI_CHOICES.append(temp)

            super(PrenotaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        print("EEEEEEEEEEEEEEE" + str(self.ORARI_CHOICES))
```

Now, `PrenotaForm.ORARI_CHOICES` is already accessible. `PrenotaForm.ORARI_CHOICES` will always be accessible, but it returns empty `list`, untill you do not create instance of `PrenotaForm`. After instance creation of `PrenotaForm`, `__init__` method will be called and data will be added inside `ORARI_CHOICES`.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply that seems to be hint I was looking for, but when i call 'print(PrenotaForm.ORARI_CHOICES)' outside the __init__ now I get the error NameError: name 'PrenotaForm' is not defined, if instead I call it as follow : "    print(ORARI_CHOICES)" I get "NameError: name 'ORARI_CHOICES' is not defined", I must having missing something, I'm indagating for a solution following your hint

Comment: Show us code. Where you are trying to access ORARI_CHOICES ?

Comment: I updated code and add more details about how it works. Read it and analyze in details.

Comment: I believe I'm missing a central point, am I wrong that I do create a new instance of `PrenotaForm` everytime the following view code is executed: `form = PrenotaForm(ORARI_CHOICES_NEW = orari_dict)`? so fixing the code as you suggested, the class/static attribute `ORARI_CHOICES = []` should be populated everytime at every page refresh (GET request defined in views.py)

But it does not seems to happen actually

Comment: do you think I should instantiate the class in an other way, perhaps directly into forms.py init method?

Comment: In general you are using `Form` class in a wrong way. `form = PrenotaForm(ORARI_CHOICES_NEW=orari_dict) # What this mean ?` what is `ORARI_CHOICES_NEW` here ? you are trying to pass it inside `__init__`, it raises `Exception`, I strongly believe it.

Comment: Thank you, it is what I'am thinking too, I may am using the wrong approach. I have updated the question with a really detailed explaination of the context, and the reason that bring be to the current situation. Can you please me check it, and if you want we can talk in chat a little bit?